# Convert kaitai-struct .ksy file to "pretty" tree view

Tags: kaitai-struct

I need to write documentation for a parser that was developed in Kaitai. Given a .ksy file, is there any way to produce "pretty" views of the tree?

There is a two year old fork of ksc that supports GraphViz output but the resulting output is pretty hard to work with.
(https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/4zhpvh/binary_data_formats_network_packets_archives/)

I can easily determine what the nodes are but getting their immediate parent would add very useful context.

Thank you.

-David

Comment: I think he means something like this:
https://formats.kaitai.io/doom_wad/

Answer (score 1):

Please define what exactly do you expect from a "pretty tree".

GraphViz support is available in master and stable releases for a long time (as `-t graphviz`), and is very well supported — basically every ksy in official repo  is accompanied nowadays with a chart: for example, http://formats.kaitai.io/lzh/index.html

If you want to have a tree of values (as opposed to "tree of data types"), we actually have [ksdump](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_visualizer/blob/master/bin/ksdump), which allows you to dump arbitary data file using arbitrary .ksy in a YAML/JSON/XML tree of values. Will it work for you?